# Error when trying to disable button until user input numbers in otp field in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
      otp_value: '', 
      isFadeout: false,
     
     verifyOtp() {
          this.disabled = true;
          this.otpBtnClicked = false;
          this.verified = true;
         },
```

```html
 <input
                              class="otp-number-login"
                              type="number"
                              v-for="(key, i) in activationKeyFields"
                              :key="i"
                              :data-length="key.length"
                              :data-index="i"
                              :ref="`input-${i}`"
                              v-model="key.value"
                              @input="handleActivationInput($event)"
                              placeholder="-"
                              maxlength="1"
                            />
 <button
                            class="verify-button-otp pxy_0"
                            v-on:click="isFadeout = true"
                            :disabled="otp_value.length < 4"
                            @click="verifyOtp"
                            id="verifybtn"
                          >
                            VERIFY
                          </button>
```

I am having otp field followed by a button. Logic for the otp is working fine.

But the issue is, After user entering the otp number in fields, and clicking on the verify button isFadeout is not working. and once if i close the otp filed and once again if i click on verify without entering number it is verifying.

Comment: Please, note that you should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Linek, I have edited my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your button

```
 <button
  class="verify-button-otp pxy_0"
  :disabled="otp_value.length < 4"
  @click="verifyOtp"
  id="verifybtn"
>

verifyOpt() {
  isFadeout = true;
  ...
}
```

you have both `v-on:click` and `@click`. @Click is just shorthand for v-on:click so your @click is overridding your logic for isFadeout. Just put your `isFadeout = true` inside of the `verifyOpt` method

Comment: Tried above code but still the same issue. Do we need to pass any reference to the button from the input field.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with the inputs and how that relates to the button, but what I said is for sure part of the problem